# Java HTTP Socket end of stream?

Tags: java, sockets, http

For a networking homework we need to create an HTTP client (versions 1.1). The problem is that

```
OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);

writer.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
writer.println("Host: " + uri.getHost());
writer.println("Accept: text/html");
writer.println();

InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
return builder.toString();
```

hangs at the end of the input, since we use http 1.1, we cannot simply close the connection. so how do I detect the end of the input?

Answer (score 1):

> so how do I detect the end of the input?

By following the standard. [RFC 2616 section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) clearly describes how the message length is specified. In short and in this order:

- some response codes mean that there is no body at all
- if Transfer-Encoding chunked is used the length is not known up-front but instead the response consists of several chunks, each one prefixed with the length
- if Content-length header is given it contains the length
- a response with content-type multipart/byteranges ends according to the MIME specification
- and finally the response might end with server closing the connection